# What is the best way to set size and position props for this image slider?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I found a similar approach but it doesn't look a good option.

```
 props: {
...
            height: {
                type: Number,
                default: 400
            },
            width: {
                type: Number,
                default: 700
            }
        },
```

How can I improve this height and width props and add position as a prop so the image baner can positioned anywhere dynamically wth dynamic size as well?

Comment: Got a jsfiddle or sandbox? I can make some "recommendations" but if you can show some working code you may be able to get a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add props for both `posX` and `posY` for instance:

```
props: {
...
  height: {
    type: Number,
    default: 400
  },
  width: {
    type: Number,
    default: 700
  }, 
  posX: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }, 
  posY: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
},
```

Or you could use an `object` prop

```
props: {
...
  height: {
    type: Number,
    default: 400
  },
  width: {
    type: Number,
    default: 700
  }, 
  position: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({x: 0, y: 0})
  },
},
```

Comment: What about improving height and width? For responsiveness, if you define value for one than another dimension should be auto right? For not making image ugly. How can be it achieved? Let's say if the height is 700 then the width is auto and the same vise a versa with 400 width e.g....

Comment: Is there any way for height and width props to make more dynamic and more correct?